# EmailMessageInterface backward compatibility issue patch for Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2.3, patches

Has anyone had success with applying the following patch

https://magento.com/tech-resources/download#download2333

I think process is

`composer require cweagans/composer-patches`

```
Path to patch: "patches/composer/EmailMessageInterface_2.3.3_backward_compatibility_composer-2019-10-30-10-20-09.patch"
```

edit composer.json

```
  "extra": {
      "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
      "patches": {
          "magento/module-email": {
              "EmailMessageInterface backward compatibility issue patch for Magento 2.3.3": "patches/composer/EmailMessageInterface_2.3.3_backward_compatibility_composer-2019-10-30-10-20-09.patch"
          }
      }
  }
```

*From here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/patching.html*

But got error.  I even tried on vanilla 2.3.3 zip from download section on site

I prefer to commit patches to repo rather than just apply to give accountability

`composer -v install`

`composer update --lock`

Here's install error

```
Mage233# composer -v install
Gathering patches for root package.
Removing package magento/module-email so that it can be re-installed and re-patched.
  - Removing magento/module-email (101.0.3)
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Dependency resolution completed in 0.015 seconds
Analyzed 935 packages to resolve dependencies
Analyzed 6246 rules to resolve dependencies
Gathering patches for root package.
Gathering patches for dependencies. This might take a minute.
Found 1 patches for magento/module-email.
  - Installing magento/module-email (101.0.3)
    Downloading: 100%         
    Extracting archive

  - Applying patches for magento/module-email
    patches/composer/EmailMessageInterface_2.3.3_backward_compatibility_composer-2019-10-30-10-20-09.patch (EmailMessageInterface backward compatibility issue patch for Magento 2.3.3)
patch '-p1' --no-backup-if-mismatch -d '/home/dominic/Git/Mage233/vendor/magento/module-email' < '/home/dominic/Git/Mage233/patches/composer/EmailMessageInterface_2.3.3_backward_compatibility_composer-2019-10-30-10-20-09.patch'
can't find file to patch at input line 5
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Transport.php b/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Transport.php
|index cbce1682cb5..79ceb56a883 100644
|--- a/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Transport.php
|+++ b/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Transport.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

2 out of 2 hunks ignored

can't find file to patch at input line 32
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Customer/Controller/AccountTest.php b/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Customer/Controller/AccountTest.php
|index 32f12dada57..4210312c55a 100644
|--- a/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Customer/Controller/AccountTest.php
|+++ b/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Customer/Controller/AccountTest.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

1 out of 1 hunk ignored

can't find file to patch at input line 45
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Mail/EmailMessageTest.php b/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Mail/EmailMessageTest.php
|index 10a54b4e1b8..186c3e2796c 100644
|--- a/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Mail/EmailMessageTest.php
|+++ b/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Mail/EmailMessageTest.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

3 out of 3 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 114
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessage.php b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessage.php
|index aaef9750751..02c75977cd0 100644
|--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessage.php
|+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessage.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

13 out of 13 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 308
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessageInterface.php b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessageInterface.php
|index 95f83ff679c..93eaa4acde3 100644
|--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessageInterface.php
|+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessageInterface.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

2 out of 2 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 338
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/MailMessageInterface.php b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/MailMessageInterface.php
|index da010be2702..5179e6057c4 100644
|--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/MailMessageInterface.php
|+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/MailMessageInterface.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

1 out of 1 hunk ignored

can't find file to patch at input line 351
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Message.php b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Message.php
|index b15b75ca9ac..1f423e80108 100644
|--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Message.php
|+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Message.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

1 out of 1 hunk ignored

can't find file to patch at input line 373
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php
|index 4a8d6572faa..2d28e2f560a 100644
|--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php
|+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

1 out of 1 hunk ignored

patch '-p0' --no-backup-if-mismatch -d '/home/dominic/Git/Mage233/vendor/magento/module-email' < '/home/dominic/Git/Mage233/patches/composer/EmailMessageInterface_2.3.3_backward_compatibility_composer-2019-10-30-10-20-09.patch'
can't find file to patch at input line 5
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Transport.php b/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Transport.php
|index cbce1682cb5..79ceb56a883 100644
|--- a/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Transport.php
|+++ b/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Transport.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

2 out of 2 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 32
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Customer/Controller/AccountTest.php b/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Customer/Controller/AccountTest.php
|index 32f12dada57..4210312c55a 100644
|--- a/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Customer/Controller/AccountTest.php
|+++ b/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Customer/Controller/AccountTest.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 45
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Mail/EmailMessageTest.php b/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Mail/EmailMessageTest.php
|index 10a54b4e1b8..186c3e2796c 100644
|--- a/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Mail/EmailMessageTest.php
|+++ b/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Mail/EmailMessageTest.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

3 out of 3 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 114
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------

|diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessage.php b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessage.php
|index aaef9750751..02c75977cd0 100644
|--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessage.php
|+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessage.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

13 out of 13 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 308
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------

|diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessageInterface.php b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessageInterface.php
|index 95f83ff679c..93eaa4acde3 100644
|--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessageInterface.php
|+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessageInterface.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

2 out of 2 hunks ignored

can't find file to patch at input line 338
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/MailMessageInterface.php b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/MailMessageInterface.php
|index da010be2702..5179e6057c4 100644
|--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/MailMessageInterface.php
|+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/MailMessageInterface.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

1 out of 1 hunk ignored

can't find file to patch at input line 351
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Message.php b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Message.php
|index b15b75ca9ac..1f423e80108 100644
|--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Message.php
|+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Message.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

1 out of 1 hunk ignored

can't find file to patch at input line 373
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php
|index 4a8d6572faa..2d28e2f560a 100644
|--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php
|+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

1 out of 1 hunk ignored

patch '-p2' --no-backup-if-mismatch -d '/home/dominic/Git/Mage233/vendor/magento/module-email' < '/home/dominic/Git/Mage233/patches/composer/EmailMessageInterface_2.3.3_backward_compatibility_composer-2019-10-30-10-20-09.patch'
can't find file to patch at input line 5
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Transport.php b/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Transport.php
|index cbce1682cb5..79ceb56a883 100644
|--- a/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Transport.php
|+++ b/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Transport.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

2 out of 2 hunks ignored

can't find file to patch at input line 32
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Customer/Controller/AccountTest.php b/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Customer/Controller/AccountTest.php
|index 32f12dada57..4210312c55a 100644
|--- a/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Customer/Controller/AccountTest.php
|+++ b/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Customer/Controller/AccountTest.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

1 out of 1 hunk ignored

can't find file to patch at input line 45
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Mail/EmailMessageTest.php b/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Mail/EmailMessageTest.php
|index 10a54b4e1b8..186c3e2796c 100644
|--- a/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Mail/EmailMessageTest.php
|+++ b/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Mail/EmailMessageTest.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

3 out of 3 hunks ignored

can't find file to patch at input line 114
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessage.php b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessage.php
|index aaef9750751..02c75977cd0 100644
|--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessage.php
|+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessage.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

13 out of 13 hunks ignored

can't find file to patch at input line 308
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessageInterface.php b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessageInterface.php
|index 95f83ff679c..93eaa4acde3 100644
|--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessageInterface.php
|+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessageInterface.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

2 out of 2 hunks ignored

can't find file to patch at input line 338
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/MailMessageInterface.php b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/MailMessageInterface.php
|index da010be2702..5179e6057c4 100644
|--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/MailMessageInterface.php
|+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/MailMessageInterface.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

1 out of 1 hunk ignored

can't find file to patch at input line 351
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Message.php b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Message.php
|index b15b75ca9ac..1f423e80108 100644
|--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Message.php
|+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Message.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

1 out of 1 hunk ignored

can't find file to patch at input line 373
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php
|index 4a8d6572faa..2d28e2f560a 100644
|--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php
|+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

1 out of 1 hunk ignored

patch '-p4' --no-backup-if-mismatch -d '/home/dominic/Git/Mage233/vendor/magento/module-email' < '/home/dominic/Git/Mage233/patches/composer/EmailMessageInterface_2.3.3_backward_compatibility_composer-2019-10-30-10-20-09.patch'
patching file Model/Transport.php

can't find file to patch at input line 32
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Customer/Controller/AccountTest.php b/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Customer/Controller/AccountTest.php
|index 32f12dada57..4210312c55a 100644
|--- a/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Customer/Controller/AccountTest.php
|+++ b/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Customer/Controller/AccountTest.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

1 out of 1 hunk ignored

can't find file to patch at input line 45
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Mail/EmailMessageTest.php b/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Mail/EmailMessageTest.php
|index 10a54b4e1b8..186c3e2796c 100644
|--- a/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Mail/EmailMessageTest.php
|+++ b/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Mail/EmailMessageTest.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

3 out of 3 hunks ignored

can't find file to patch at input line 114
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessage.php b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessage.php
|index aaef9750751..02c75977cd0 100644
|--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessage.php
|+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessage.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

13 out of 13 hunks ignored

can't find file to patch at input line 308
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessageInterface.php b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessageInterface.php
|index 95f83ff679c..93eaa4acde3 100644
|--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessageInterface.php
|+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessageInterface.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

2 out of 2 hunks ignored

can't find file to patch at input line 338
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/MailMessageInterface.php b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/MailMessageInterface.php
|index da010be2702..5179e6057c4 100644
|--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/MailMessageInterface.php
|+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/MailMessageInterface.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

1 out of 1 hunk ignored

can't find file to patch at input line 351
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Message.php b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Message.php
|index b15b75ca9ac..1f423e80108 100644
|--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Message.php
|+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Message.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

1 out of 1 hunk ignored

can't find file to patch at input line 373
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php
|index 4a8d6572faa..2d28e2f560a 100644
|--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php
|+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.

1 out of 1 hunk ignored

   Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch patches/composer/EmailMessageInterface_2.3.3_backward_compatibility_composer-2019-10-30-10-20-09.patch


  [Exception]                                                                  
  Cannot apply patch EmailMessageInterface backward compatibility issue patch  
   for Magento 2.3.3 (patches/composer/EmailMessageInterface_2.3.3_backward_c  
  ompatibility_composer-2019-10-30-10-20-09.patch)!
```

Comment: No one else tried applying this patch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in summary can't use composer for reasons stated in other answer

Inside webroot

`patch -p1 < EmailMessageInterface_2.3.3_backward_compatibility_composer-2019-10-14-03-43-31.patch`

Untracked in versioning

Answer (score 1):

In order to use *cweagans/composer-patches*, patches must be split per package. Patch that we released affects multiple packages, this is why you can't install it with *cweagans/composer-patches*. I explained [here](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Backward-incompatible-Changes-in-the-Mail-Library-for-Magento-2/bc-p/214418/highlight/true#M611) how you can install this patch.

Some of the files that patch modifies located in the dev folder which is part of *magento/magento2-base* package. *cweagans/composer-patches* removes packages and then installs them again. As it's not possible to remove *magento/magento2-base*, *cweagans/composer-patches* can't be used to modify all files that need to be patched. This is why we would not be releasing version of the patch that you can install with *cweagans/composer-patches*. Refer to the link above for instructions to this patch.

Comment: Makes sense. I recommend that https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/patching.html is updated to reflect the above.