# How do i apply path APPSEC-1679 for Magento 2.3.1 via composer

Tags: patches, magento2.3.1, magento-ee

Could you please provide the clear steps to apply the patch via composer for Magento 2.3.1 version.

> APPSEC-1679 - API ACL - Failed.
>
> API ACL Patch not detected

Comment: Have you patch file?

Comment: No I need to update only via composer

Comment: Get reference from here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/patching.html

Comment: I read those docs and tried this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/294379/emailmessageinterface-backward-compatibility-issue-patch-for-magento-2-3-3 I would be interested to know whether this particular patch applies using composer method and Mage2.3.1