# Composer error when try install extension

Tags: magento2.3, composer

I'm getting this when i'm trying to install an extension.

> Warning: Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in
>   /home/SITE_NAME/public_html/vendor/magento/inventory-composer-installer/src/Plugin.php
>   on line 6
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in
>   /home/SITE_NAME/public_html/vendor/magento/inventory-composer-installer/src/Plugin.php
>   on line 55

**I have : CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core); PHP 7.2 (via cPanel) ; Latest magento 2.3.3 CE**

**php -v
PHP 5.6.40 (cli) (built: Oct 29 2019 08:07:50)**

Need Some Help

Comment: Your command line is using php5.6. Need to use php7. I just typed up how to use alias to run composer with different php versions on cpanel server https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/294937/70343

Answer (score 0):

either you could update your php to 7.X version or downgrade your ProxyManager. this will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my issue I have resolved it like this
php /path_to_composer/composer.phar install
So try to find right version of php and run composer by php